# Delete a item in mobile menu via Custom.css

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I need to delete one item in my mobile menu via `Custom.css`. I don't want to edit other files in WordPress.

This is screen of my mobile menu items. And I want delete just one position. It's easy to do that via Google Chrome editor, but what do I need to add in my custom.css to save this permanently?

Screen of my menu before originally:

[image]

Link to website: http://test.projekt-tenis.pl/wordpress/

All i want is to delete only  :  " Oferta " from the menu.

After editing it in google chrome my menu looks like  : 
[image]
As you can see " Ofera" is deleted.
I want just do this via Custom.css. I saw a few topic about it but still don't know how can i  do that.

Comment: LoL. Actually I am amused looking at the Close Vote - How else can this person can add more information? There's enough information here. Please understand that there are limitations and this is one such kind of question, where you can't put any more information.

Comment: @PraveenKumar Pictures of code means the questioner is asking you to type in the code yourself. That is like me posting an answer to the question as a picture. So it's as if no markup was posted at all and images are not searchable. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @Rob There's no code in this. Tell me specific to this question. Do you think the user can do something about this? Think this way. Let's say the user hasn't given the images but the code just like that I would have definitely stammered. This is not about the code. But ... Well, I hope you understand how. The dev tools and the front end has to be shown in this case...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should fix it. We don't need to delete the DOM node using JavaScript or something. Each and every menu item in WordPress can be uniquely identified using their Post ID. In your case, it is **988**. We can use `display: none;` for that particular element and hide it using CSS. This is the sole reason for having `@media` queries.

Use this CSS in your `custom.css`.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {
  #menu-item-988 {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

I am targeting the clients with a screen size of `960px` or less, which can be loosely considered to be a mobile device. You can always refer to CSS Tricks' [Media Queries for Standard Devices](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/).

**Preview:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Deleting" an item from the DOM can be done in a variety of ways. I imagine what you're going for can be achieved with a simple `display: none;` property assigned to that item in your CSS file, this will remove the element visually but will not delete it from DOM.

Comment: `display:none;` does not delete an element from the DOM.

Comment: You are correct, and while it may seem that this is what I was saying it is not, but I'll modify my answer to clarify.